# How do you sort NSMutableArray from JSON in swift?

Tags: ios, json, sorting, swift, nsmutablearray

I made a UITableview with NSMutableArray, having data downloaded from server in form of JSON.  When I perform the table cell the code goes like below.

```
if let rstrntName = self.items[indexPath.row]["rstrnt_name"] as? NSString {
    cell.rstrntName.text = rstrntName
}
```

Now I want to sort it by a column named "rstrnt_name".  Below is the code I tried, but it doesn't work.

```
self.items.sortedArrayUsingComparator({obj1, obj2 -> NSComparisonResult in
    let rstrnt1: NSDictionary = obj1 as NSDictionary
    let rstrnt2: NSDictionary = obj2 as NSDictionary
    if (rstrnt1["rstrnt_name"] as String) < (rstrnt2["rstrnt_name"] as String) {
        return NSComparisonResult.OrderedAscending
    }
    if (rstrnt1["rstrnt_name"] as String) > (rstrnt2["rstrnt_name"] as String) {
        return NSComparisonResult.OrderedDescending
    }
    return NSComparisonResult.OrderedSame
})
```

How can I sort objects in such type?

Comment: Btw, if you can use swift arrays, the approach is nicer and an example is here (search on page for sort): https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html

Comment: Could you send code from from the area where you added items in the self.items array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign the sorted array to anywhere and check -

```
self.items = self.items.sortedArrayUsingComparator(//rest of your code
```

should give you the sorted result.

Comment: Thank you.  I changed the type into NSArray then the assigning worked.

Answer (score 1):

`self.items.sortedArrayUsingComparator` returns a sorted array which you appear to be throwing away to the ether. Try storing the value instead.

Answer (score 1):

Here is swift `Array` types sort method with pattern matching. This `sort` method directly mutates `items` doesn't return new one.

```
var items: [[String: AnyObject]] = [["rstrnt_name": "mustafa"], ["rstrnt_name": "Ray"], ["rstrnt_name": "Ali"]]

items.sort { (left, right) -> Bool in
    let first = left["rstrnt_name"] as? String
    let second = right["rstrnt_name"] as? String

    switch (first, second) {
    case let (.Some(x), .Some(y)): return x < y
    default: return false
    }
}
```